# Adding Serial Number in mysql successfully but unknown column when use in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I fetch results according to winning in descending order. But I need id for Load More function.
I have successfully added serial number but for load more function i want to use serial number id to get the result and not repeating the result. But when I use into where clause I get error unknown column.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have deleted the stuff, as I post my answer.

Comment: mysql error 1064 is syntax error, please read error message and follow that.

Comment: is there anyone who help me out ? I just want to fetch query via added serial number in where clause. I found no where so i ask here to respected experts

Comment: *But when I use into where clause I get error unknown column.* Show precise SQL code and complete according error message.

Comment: There is no column headed `pic_status` shown in that image

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular pic_status only for pic is active or not, it doesn't affect the query , I want to use with that serial number

Comment: Of course it affects the query. You're specifically asking for rows with `pic_status = 1`. There's no column by that name, nor any alias, nor any calculated value. The error message is telling you that. Where do you expect `pic_status` to come from?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, I have edited the question , please have a look. I added the error message image & pic_status image as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from (
    SELECT  rank()over(order by pic_wins desc) as serial_number,
            pic_id, 
            pic_caption, 
            pic_image, 
            pic_wins 
    FROM pics
        WHERE pic_status = '1' 
    order by pic_wins desc
) as foo
  where serial_number=1;
```

you can't use alias in where clause but you can use it an sub query

And if you want continuous series in serial_number use `dense_rank()`

Comment: Thanks for the help @dgnk , but here is an error i.e. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by pic_wins desc) as serial_number,
            pic_id,
            pi' at line 2

Comment: For rank to work OP has to be on version 8 or above, the fact rank is not already used indicates that not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, I got my answer to little modify @dgnk answer

```
select * from ( SELECT @s:=@s+1 serial_number, pic_id, pic_caption, pic_image, pic_wins FROM pics, (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s WHERE pic_status = '1' order by pic_wins desc ) as foo where serial_number > 8
```